# How do I break line in this case: Welhome: 'Welcome home\nNext task starts in',

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a vuejs project,I want the output of `Welhome: 'Welcome home\nNext task starts in'`  to be in two lines, break after home, see below

Expected output:

```
Welcome home
Next task starts in
```

Actual output:

```
Welcome homeNext task starts in
```

I have tried `Welhome: 'Welcome home\nNext task starts in'` but this didnt work.
I am using Welhome at some components to get this text.

using that inside computed property as below

```
  getLabelText() {
      if (!this.isMembersRequired) {
        return textUtils.Welhome;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that when inserting text nodes into HTML, line breaks should be represented as `<br />`, unless you are using `white-space: pre`, then the new line characters will be parsed as such.

Comment: I have tried doing Welcome home<br/>Next task starts in. but this doesn't work, it prints <br/> as text obviously

Comment: You should be using the `v-html` binding instead: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: I am using this inside a computed property

Comment: Share your code: it's not possible to see what you're doing from comments alone. Update your question instead.

Comment: updated with the computed property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre-line` property on the element that would display the text. This would ensure `\n` would take effect. Another solution would be to use the `pre` element as it would respect `\n`.

Comment: Glad you have your solution!